# Como posso fazer um bot de Registro por Reação Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventos

Queria saber como eu posso fazer uma função no meu bot com Discord.js de registro por reações adicionadas em uma certa mensagem?

Vi alguns tutoriais usando o objeto `raw` porém nenhum atualmente funciona. Meu codigo atualmente está parecido com esse:

```
client.on('raw', async dados => {
    if(dados.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD" && dados.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE") return
    if(dados.d.message_id != "566982078625873931") return

    let servidor = client.guilds.get("558703169903788057")
    let membro = servidor.members.get(dados.d.user_id)

    let cargo = servidor.roles.get('566986334242340864'),


    if(dados.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){
        if(dados.d.emoji.id === "566966275578789888"){
            if(membro.roles.has(cargo)) return
            membro.addRole(cargo)
        }
    }
    if(dados.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE"){
        if(dados.d.emoji.id === "566966275578789888"){
            if(membro.roles.has(cargo)) return
            membro.removeRole(cargo)
        }
    }

})

*Levando em conta que estou usando a versão 12 do Discord.js, e esse código foi feito na versão 11*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primeiro, para qual motivo você quer manipular essa reações?

---

Na verdade há vários motivos para você querer usar a manipulação de reações, vou listar alguns:

- Criar um registro com reações *(Esse com certeza é um dos motivos mais procurados, e mais usados)*.
- Abre um leque de opções para fazer confirmações *(Nos gatilhos de reações você pode aninhar qualquer função, tanto de confirmação ou execução de alguma função)*.

---

### O que é Necessário saber?

- Estou levando em conta que você já tenha um `bot` funcional usando **discord.js**, se não antes de usar essa resposta leia o **[guia](https://discordjs.guide/)** do Discord.js *(Esse guia há todos os tutorias para você ter um **bot** pelo menos básico e funcional)*.

---

### Partials

- É uma função recentemente adicionada, na versão 12 do discord.js, antes para criar esse tipo de interação com reações era usado o método *raw*, esse método ainda existe, porém como reações em mensagens antigas não são armazenadas em cache e o *raw* é um evento suscetível a muitos erros não é o ideal usar esse método. *(Provavelmente ele nem é mais funcional em manipulação de reações)*.

**Como funciona uma parcial:**

- Antes de tudo é necessário ativar essa parcial, já que ela **não** está habilitada por padrão. No seu arquivo *main* substitua a `require` do do *Discord.js* por:

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] })
```

*Há varias estruturas nas `partials`, mas por agora essas são mais do que necessárias.* Se quiser saber mais sobre as `partials` use o **[guia de parciais](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials)** do *Discord.js*!

### Criando evento de ReactionAdd

- Primeiro temos que criar o evento que vai observar essas reações, esse evento se chama: `messageReactionAdd` e vamos usar ele dessa forma:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    //Código de reação
})
```

> O que ele está fazendo é observar o evento de **Adicionar Reação** e passando a *reação* e o *usuário* para podermos usar para confirmação e comandos futuros.

**Usando a Parcial**

- Dentro desse evento devemos declarar a `partial` da seguinte forma:

```
    if(reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Alguma coisa está errada quando tento puxara a reação!')
            return
        }
    }
```

> Usando um modelo de *trycatch* padrão usamos a parcial e capturamos o erro se necessário.

**Declarando o objeto `guild`:**

- Você também precisa ter o `guild` definido, ele vai pegar o id do seu servidor e transformar em um objeto que você possa usar, você pode fazer isso declarando uma constante também dentro do evento:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("<ID DO SEU SERVIDOR>")
```

**Declarando as Roles**

- Como estamos fazendo uma função de registro por reação também temos que declarar as roles que vamos adicionar para os usuários, desta forma:

```
const <nome da role> = guild.roles.cache.get("<ID da role>")
```

> Declaramos que a `role` tem esse id, pegando todas as propriedades atreladas a `role` em questão. Você pode fazer isso com um objeto ou uma array também, e pode fazer com quantas roles for necessárias.

**Achando o membro que reagiu:**

- Agora vamos ter que pegar quem reagiu a mensagem, isso parece simples, *é só pegar o `user` do evento e usar ele certo?* **Não!**

> O `user` trás um usuário do Discord não um membro de guilda, então devemos transformar isso em membro dessa forma:

```
const member = reaction.message.guild.member(user)
```

> Aqui passamos o id do usuário para a função `member` que identifica o membro dentro da guilda declarada!

**Criando identificação de reação**

- Agora podemos usar esses atributos declarados!
- Dentro do evento precisamos identificar a mensagem que queremos que esse evento funcione desta forma:

```
    if(reaction.message.id !== '<ID da Mensagem>') return 
        else {
            
        }
```

> Usamos um `if else` básico para filtrar a mensagem que a gente quer pelo id.

- Agora precisamos também filtrar o `emoji` que queremos, aqui entrar também alguns adendos:

1. Os emojis `normais`, os que podem ser usados em qualquer site exemplo: "" o Discord os trata como nomes.
2. Os emojis criados dentro de uma guilda o discord os trata como id's.

- Dentro do else vamos fazer desta forma:

```
//...
   else {
         if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
           //...     
         }
     }
```

> Se no caso você estiver usando um emoji personalizado, faça desta forma:

```
//...
   else {
         if(reaction.emoji.id === "<ID do Emoji>") {
           //...     
         }
     }
```

- Você pode obter esse id dessa seguinte forma:

1. Vá ao chat do servido e use `\<Emoji>`
2. Ele vai trazer para você esse codigo:`<a:sintonia_emoji96:665606434595274762>` , use somente os números desse código. Voilà, você tem seu id.

- Para parte final vamos verificar se o membro já possui a role e adiciona-la, nesse ponto seu código já deve estar desta forma:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Alguma coisa está errada quando tento puxara a reação!')
            return
        }
    }

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("796513382060392451");

    const role = guild.roles.cache.get("797336187874312232")

    const member = reaction.message.guild.member(user)

    if(reaction.message.id !== '797336187874312156') return 
        else {
            if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {

            }
        }

})
```

- Dentro desse ultimo *if* adicione:

```
//...
            if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                if(member.roles.cache.has(fem)) return
                    else {
                        
                    }
            }
```

> Agora estamos verificando se o membro já tem essa role, se ele possuir ele responde um return vazio, não fazendo nada!

- Dentro desse `else`:

```
//...
                    else {
                        member.roles.add(role)
                    }
```

- Assim terminamos o código, dito isso, se a pessoa reagir a essa mensagem com esse *emoji* definido, vai ser adicionado a role. Para fazer o inverso, mude o evento para: `'messageReactionRemove'`, use a mesma estrutura e ao invés de:

```
   member.roles.add(role)
```

- Use no if de confirmação de role:

```
   member.roles.remove(role)
```

- No final seu código deve estar parecido com isso:

> [Pastebin](https://gist.github.com/Ellathet/6bcd2d7739e723677e0bad02e069677c)

Answer (score -2):

vc pegou o codigo do PR?

vc deve por cache antes dos get.
ex: let servidor = client.guilds.cache.get("558703169903788057")

no discord.js v12 nao se usa mais addRole e sim roles.add.
ex: membro.roles.add(cargo) ou membro.roles.remove(cargo)

e esse if(membro.roles.has(cargo)) return eu tirei e funcionou tranquilo.